# Oracle SQL Syntax: V$ views

Tags: oracle, view

I've noticed that Oracle comes with some special tables/views (e.g. `V$SESSION`) that are not contained in `dba_tables` nor in `dba_views`.

Why is that?

Can someone explain when tables or views are part of `dba_tables` / `dba_views` and when not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All views are listed in `DBA_VIEWS`.

Oracle's V$ objects are actually public synonyms (and they do appear in `DBA_SYNONYMS`).  `V$SESSION` is a synonym for `SYS.V_$SESSION` which does appear in `DBA_VIEWS`.  In general, the `V$` objects are public synonyms for views in the SYS schema with the prefix `V_$` and the `GV$` are public synonyms for views in the SYS schema with the prefix `GV_$`.

Answer (score 1):

> Throughout its operation, Oracle
>   Database maintains a set of virtual
>   tables that record current database
>   activity. These views are called
>   dynamic performance views because they
>   are continuously updated while a
>   database is open and in use. The
>   views, also sometimes called V$ views

...I'll let Oracle [explain](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_part.htm#REFRN003) ;)  Also see [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/datadict.htm).